how to convert the result from openai call, convert it into json and write to .txt file?
I am very new to python and only know the basics, so basically I am calling openai and getting a response in return and want to write that response in a .txt file.
I want to convert the response in json before writing in the file. my response is already in json format but weird when print it shows json format with json {}  with it, this is my script
def get_json(image_file, category):
    with open(image_file, "rb") as image:
        response = openai_client.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-4-vision-preview",
            messages=[
                {
                    "role": "user",
                    "content": [
                        {"type": "text", "text": f"Analyze this image and provide the following attributes: color theme, font style, and a short description of about 4-7 words. Categorize it as {category}. Return the result as a JSON object."},
                        {"type": "image_url", "image_url": {"url": f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64.b64encode(image.read()).decode()}"}},
                    ],
                }
            ],
            temperature=1,
            max_tokens=4095,
            top_p=1,
            frequency_penalty=0,
            presence_penalty=0,
        ) 
        return response.choices[0].message.content
     
with open(file, 'a') as file:
    for filename in os.listdir(images_folder):
        filepath = os.path.join(images_folder, filename)
        result =get_json(filepath, 'hero')
        file.write(result + '\n')
        json_result = json.loads(result)
        print(json_result)

this is the result i am getting
enter image description here
i want to remove the text '''json'''
tried to convert it into json by json.loads(result) but getting the following error:-
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

You are asking it to return a JSON object in you prompt, "Return the result as a JSON object." that it why! If you give it the same prompt using the website, you will notice that the response is nicely formatted, that is because of those "```json ...content ```" markdown formatting.
You can solve it using two methods:

Explicitly replace "```json" and "```" with empty string:

import json

# For example, this is the content in response:
response = '```json{"color_theme": "Mint Green and Black","font_style": "Sans-serif","short_description": "Web Publishing Platform","category": "hero"}```'

# Replace and assign back to original content
response = response.replace("```json", "")
response = response.replace("```", "")

# Don't forget to convert to JSON as it is a string right now:
json_result = json.loads(response)


Using slicing:

import json

# For example, this is the content in response:
response = '```json{"color_theme": "Mint Green and Black","font_style": "Sans-serif","short_description": "Web Publishing Platform","category": "hero"}```'

# "```json" is 7 character long, but slicing count start from 0. "{" is at 7th character.
# "```" is 3 character long (at the end).
response = response[7:-3]

# Don't forget to convert to JSON as it is a string right now:
json_result = json.loads(response)


And for writing to the .txt file, you can use json.dump() as follows:
import json

response = '```json{"color_theme": "Mint Green and Black","font_style": "Sans-serif","short_description": "Web Publishing Platform","category": "hero"}```'

response = response[7:-3]
response = json.loads(response)

# Write to response.txt file (overwriting it).
with open("response.txt", "w") as file:
    json.dump(response, file)

